# ¿Los eventos de formularios ocurren en diferentes Hilos? C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, hilos, eventos

¿Los eventos de formularios ocurren en diferentes Hilos? por ejemplo si yo tengo un panel en el formulario en el cual tengo el evento Click y tengo un evento keyDown en el formulario y activo los 2 eventos al mismo tiempo (hago click en el formulario y presiono alguna tecla en el teclado) mi duda es, el codigo que tenga en los 2 eventos se reproducira al mismo tiempo? o solo hara un evento? aqui un ejemplo

```
    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
            Console.WriteLine($"{e.X} " + $"{e.Y}");
    }

    private void Pantalla_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Console.WriteLine($"click");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Los eventos de un formulario ocurren en un único hilo que es el hilo del interfaz.**

Tal como funciona windows, hay un bucle while esperando por eventos. Cuando llega un evento, este se procesa y luego se vuelve al while a esperar el siguiente.

Mientras un evento no termine, no se ejecuta el siguiente. Asi que, contestando a tu pregunta. **No, no se reproducirán al mismo tiempo los eventos. Primero se ejecutará uno y luego otro.**

De hecho, si arrancas un thread dentro de tu código e intentas modificar algo del interfaz (el color de un botón por ejemplo) te va dar una excepción ya que el interfaz está protegido para que solo el thread principal pueda manipularlo.

Una aplicación se queda congelada precisamente porque un evento tarda mucho en ejecutarse y no se ejecutan los siguientes eventos de dibujo del interfaz.

Hay varias formas de que "mejorar" la respuesta de un formulario, la más fácil de usar es usar código asíncrono ya que no implica nuevos threads por lo que el acceso al interfaz es seguro.